# Correct way to store a business's open hours, when they're open til past midnight

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app have several stores. Some stores are open from say 12PM til 04AM the following day.

The issue with our current code is that we store open time and close time. Now that means for the first day you can put 12PM - 11:59PM but the next day it's still open for another 4 hours, before it again opens up at 12PM and technically closes at 1 minute before midnight.

Does anybody have any experience with this issue, and how did you go about solving this and setting it up in the DB?

Comment: I would change the code so that you don't need to do some daft 11.59 workaround.  If there's a validation saying that closing time needs to be after opening time, for example, then take out the validation and change your logic to assume that if opening time IS after closing time, then closing time is referring to the following day.  Ie, change your app's internal logic to match the reality.

Comment: Alternately, you could change the data so that instead of storing opening time and closing time, you store opening time and opening duration.  Then the closing time can be calculated simply by adding the duration to the opening time.

Comment: It depends... What should you do with this data? Just display hours on web page? calculate work time? decide if a store works at the moment? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this and any other number of complex cases you might benefit from opening times being a relation, or some form of collection.

For example, a shop that is open from 9-5 but closes an hour for lunch would have two `open_periods`, covering each half of their day.

In this method your shop would have a period starting at midnight and ending at 4am, another starting at midday and ending at 23:59:59.

I would suggest then coupling this with an "opening_times" string field for a simple, human readable opening times string.

Add to this @MaxWilliams suggestion of opening periods being a start time and a duration, and you have a very flexible system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing `[start, end]`, store `[start, duration]`.

If you want to allow for multiple intervals, store multiple of those pairs per store.

Comment: yeah, and multiple [start, end] pairs would work too